# How to overload template class by type- and non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading, metaprogramming

Is it possible to implement a template class `Type` which supports the following instantiations?

```
Type<int> typeArg_;
Type<nullptr> nonTypeArg_;
```

I hope there is a solution (especially without macro). Maybe `std::enable_if`-magic or something will help...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.

The nature of a template parameter is fixed. It is either a type or non-type (value). It can't be a type for one use case and a non-type for another use case.

There might be ways to accomplish your goal if you can elaborate what that is.

Answer (score -1):

As far I now, isn't possible in C++.

The best that come in my mind is to wrap values in types; something as

```
template <typename T, T Value>
struct ValueWrapper
 { };
```

and specialize `Type` for `ValueWrapper`

Something as

```
template <typename T>
struct Type
 { /* something with T */ };

template <typename T, T Value>
struct Type<ValueWrapper<T, Value>>
 { /* something with value */ };
```

The use become

```
Type<int>  typeArg;
Type<ValueWrapper<std::nullptr_t, nullptr>> nonTypeArg;

or also

Type<ValueWrapper<decltype(nullptr), nullptr>> nonTypeArg;
```

As pointed by Jarod42 (thanks) the standard (starting from C++11) provides a standard structure that make the `ValueWrapper` function: [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant).

You can use it instead of `ValueWrapper` but doesn't works, for `std::integral_constant`, the following C++17 semplification.

Because if you can use C++17, all become simpler: you can use `auto` for value types, so `ValueWrapper` become

```
template <auto Value>
struct ValueWrapper
 { };
```

so `Type` non-type specialization become

```
template <auto Value>
struct Type<ValueWrapper<Value>>
 { /* something with value */ };
```

and the use

```
Type<int>  typeArg;
Type<ValueWrapper<nullptr>> nonTypeArg;
```

Comment: why not [std::integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)  ?

Comment: because (1) I never remember it (my fault) and (2) I was thinking to modify in, the C++17 case, in `auto` version. But I'll add a note about it. Thanks.